# parse error in arry sort of keys

Tags: php, sorting

I am getting an error saying

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/ajayi/public_html/html/arrays.php on line 14

When I added the sort is when I started getting the error. What I am trying to do is have the names of the fruits sorted in alphabetical order.

this is my code...

```
$myArray = array('0' => 'tangerine' , '1' => 'orange' , '2' => 'kiwi', '3' => 'strawberry' , '4' => 'banana', '5' => 'grape', '6' => 'pear' , '7'=> 'apple');

echo "<table border ='2px black solid'>";
for ($x = 0; $x < 8; $x++){
echo "<tr>";
for($y = 0; $y < 10; $y++){
echo "<td>".sort($myArray)[$x][$y]."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
```

Comment: `sort($myArray)` doesn't return the array, does it?

Comment: @Don'tPanic - true.... sort() is "by reference"

Comment: And sorting the array every iteration is also highly inefficient

Comment: The reason for the parse error is because you're trying to index a function call. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29505827/1491895

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the position of the sort line so that the sort line is only called one time. (See comment of "Mark Baker"). The echo of the array value is still present on the original location.

```
$myArray = array('0' => 'tangerine' , '1' => 'orange' , '2' => 'kiwi', '3' => 'strawberry' , '4' => 'banana', '5' => 'grape', '6' => 'pear' , '7'=> 'apple');

sort($myArray);
echo "<table border ='2px black solid'>";
for ($x = 0; $x < 8; $x++){
    echo "<tr>";
    for($y = 0; $y < 10; $y++){
         echo "<td>" . $myArray[$x][$y] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
```